# UK Visa: convictions and other penalties

Tags: visas, uk, driving, applications

I'm applying for a UK Visa using the newest portal. One section is called *Convictions and other penalties* and asks *At any time have you ever had any of the following, in the UK or in another country?*. One voice is the following:

> A penalty for a driving offence, for example disqualification for speeding or no motor insurance.

I remember I received a ticket because I once overtook another car on the white stripes. It was probably 15 years ago but here they ask for the day, month and year, and I have absolutely no idea when this happened exactly. Moreover, on the next page they say:

> You must tell us about fixed penalty notices (e.g. a speeding or parking ticket) if you've received three or more. If you received a fixed penalty notice but didn't pay the fine and there was a criminal proceeding resulting in a conviction, tell us here.

Isn't this in contrast with what said before? Does this mean that if I received only 1 ticket I do not have to include it?

Comment: Disqualification and having no insurance are serious matters, but a fixed penalty notice means you don't get a court summons. It's like a parking fine, and is not a **conviction**.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank for the answer but I’m still not sure what to put. English isn’t my mother tongue and maybe things work differently in the UK. A police office just stopped me and gave a ticket to pay. Nothing else happened.

Comment: I have not seen the form, but from your question it looks as though the first section is for **serious** offences and convictions. If you don't have any, then the other section will apply, and you only have one fixed penalty notice.

Comment: No, the second section results from me choosing the first one. It’s like “you selected this, now tell us more”

Comment: But you *haven't received three or more.*

Comment: That’s true, but the first section says “a penalty”, so I assumed at least one.

Comment: It says "for example disqualification for speeding or no motor insurance". You have not had those. If you had no serious offences resulting in a court appearance, and you only had 1 fixed penalty ticket, there is nothing to list.

Comment: Isn’t the safest option ‘if in doubt, disclose’? If the overtaking offence doesn’t count, the ECO will ignore it. If it does count, it’s been disclosed correctly (even if the OP can’t remember the exact details).